# 2 columns in desktop, 1 in mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a question, im working with a 2 column wordpress theme made by me (www.infobaires.com.ar). It has no responsive version more than a wp-touch plugin.

I have this scheme:

1 | 2 
3 | 4 
5 | 6 
7 | 8

This is made by two columns. One floating left, and one right.

If i make some "responsive changes" it will fix like this:

Col1
1
3
5
7
Col2
2
4
6
8

THE QUESTION: How can I make this:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

This is my loop:

```
                        <?php global $post; $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=16&offset=3');    ?>
                        <div id="col1">
                        <?php
                        $i=1;
                        foreach($myposts as $post) :
                        if($i%2 != 0) :
                        setup_postdata($post);
                        $tema_especial = get_post_meta($post->ID,'tema_especial',true);
                        ?>

                        <div class="nota-c clearfix">
                        //Float right content
                        </div>

                        <?php   
                        endif;
                        $i++;
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col2">
                        <?php
                        $i=1;
                        foreach($myposts as $post) :
                        if($i%2 == 0) :
                        setup_postdata($post);
                        $tema_especial = get_post_meta($post->ID,'tema_especial',true);
                        ?>

                        <div class="nota-c clearfix">
                        //Float left content
                        </div>


                        <?php endif;
                        $i++;
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col1">1</div>
    <div class="col2">2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col1">3</div>
    <div class="col2">4</div>
</div>    <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">5</div>
    <div class="col2">6</div>
</div>    <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">7</div>
    <div class="col2">8</div>
</div>
```

on A desktop they float: left, for mobile they float: none.

Comment: Im thinking, if i use that code, i must use so many querys. For example, if i want to show 16 posts i must use 8 querys. That make my site run slow?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you won't need to make 8 queries. You can make one, and then do something like this (untested):

```
$query = new WP_Query('whatever your query is goes here');

if($query->have_posts()):
  $rows = array_chunk($query->posts, 2);
  foreach($rows as $posts):
    $counter = 1;
    echo "<div class='row'>";
      foreach($posts as $post):
        echo "<div class='col".$counter."'>";
          //Whatever your post content / links are goes here..
        echo "</div>";
        $counter++;
      endforeach; 
    echo "</div>";
  endforeach;
endif;
```